# Complex select comparison

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Hey guys i have two tables T1 and T2, T1 has a columm called time and T2 has two columms date and time. Follow the scenario

```
T1
-------------------
Time
-------------------
10:00
11:00
12:00

T2
-------------------
Date       | Time
-------------------
2013-10-01 | 10:00
2013-10-01 | 11:00
2013-10-01 | 12:00
2013-10-02 | 10:00
2013-10-02 | 11:00
```

I need write a select that return 2013-10-01 because the times of this date match with **ALL** T1 fields. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: "Complex" always lures me in, and I'm always disappointed by what I find inside.

Comment: i have no idea how to begin.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work as long as you have 3 values in T1

```
SELECT T2.Date
FROM T2
inner join T1 on T1.Time = T2.Time
GROUP BY T2.Date
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT T1.Time) = 3
```

or more "generic" but less performant:

```
SELECT T2.Date
FROM T2
INNER JOIN T1 on T1.Time = T2.Time
GROUP BY T2.Date
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT T1.Time) = (select count(distinct Time) from T1);
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ea7c4/2)

Comment: the second one fits perfect to my needs.. thanks bro